# Provisioned for the weekend

Tags: meaning, phrases, expressions, meaning-in-context, conversation

What does it mean exactly? A friend asked me if I was "provisioned for the weekend," and as someone who knows English as a second language, I was scratching my head trying to figure out what he was asking about and how I should respond.

From what little word-for-word usage of the phrase I could find on the Internet (Twitter, etc.), it seems that it is mostly used in the context of leisure (if it is ever commonly used), with people posting pictures of items intended for entertainment along with the caption.

I know that to provision means to supply/provide. In this case, does it mean "ready for the weekend?" "Prepared for the weekend?" As in spending time to enjoy the weekend?

When I isolate the word "provisioned," however, instances where the subject is prepared for a serious situation also come up, which makes me wonder even more, as my friend asked this shortly after a hurricane had hit the region I live in and I had told him my experience with the resultant rainy day prior to our conversation. Was he asking if I was physically prepared and secure for the outcome of the hurricane in the weekend to come, then?

Comment: "provisioned for the weekend," - got the beers and chips in for the big game/picnic/party/netflix...

Comment: Supplied with _provisions_ (food and drink).

Answer (score 1):

Your friend could have meant — as KillingTime suggested — beer and chips (weekend leisure food) or water and flashlights (supplies for an anticipated disaster).

Here’s what the *OED* has to say:

> **provisioned**, *adj.*
>  Supplied with provisions; *esp.* furnished with a stock of food. Frequently with modifying word.
>
> **provision**, *n.*
> **6.**
> **a.** A supply of necessities or materials; a stock or store of something.
> **c.** Usually in plural. A supply of food; food supplied or provided; victuals.
>
> <sub>Source: [Oxford English Distionary](https://oed.com) (login
> required)</sub>

(Whichever way your weekend goes, you’d probably want to have all of the above provisions on hand.)

Answer (score 0):

"Provisioned" does mean supplied or provided, but unless it specifically includes what you are "provisioned" with it is usually taken to mean "necessities".

So "Are you provisioned for the weekend?" would mean "do you have everything you need for the weekend?"

Comment: Generally concentrated on consumables -- food, drink.